# Should a I use a timeseries database to store real estate prices information?

Tags: postgresql, time-series, data-analysis, graphite, influxdb

I'm working on a personal project to analyze real estate data from three different sites. I want to do some statistical analysis (Python, numpy, pandas, scikit) an data visualization on the data to identify trends, outliers, variations on the market, opportunities, identify clusters, etc.

Part of the information to store:

- Price (**stored daily**)
- ID
- Property age
- Location (initially and string but eventually geo coordinates)
- Amenities
- Publication date
- Square foots
- Parking spaces

The total number of properties is 250.000,00. Initially I'll download the information daily to understand the characteristics of the data. After this, I will change the refresh rate of the data, probably twice a week.

I'm thinking about using a relational (PostgreSQL) database for non time dependent data and a timeseries (influxdb or graphite) database for prices.

What do you think? I'm choosing the right stack?

Comment: Timeseries database is a good choice when you have really quickly changing values over time - typically system metrics for real time monitoring and alerting. Is it so in this case? If prices are changing rather slowly like over weeks or months then with timeseries database you will just add unnecessary complexity into your app.

Comment: timeseries databases are very efficient storing this kind of information. They have ways to compress repeated information and provide functionalities to analyze time dependent data easily: https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/data_exploration/ . Aggregating these kind of data on a relational database or programatically  would be more difficult. https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v1.1/query_language/functions/

Comment: TSDB is a great choice for this, especially if they support SQL with time-series extensions. See https://github.com/axibase/atsd-docs/tree/master/api/sql#overview as an example, and a more hands-on study: https://github.com/axibase/atsd-use-cases/blob/master/USMortality

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. I'll give it a try.

Comment: Could anybody move this question to http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ ? I think it would fit much better there